# How to change the maximum value of a react native slider after it was initialized

Tags: react-native, slider

I'm trying to find a way to make the slider component from the @react-native-community/slider change it's maximumValue after it was initialized. I can't preset a maximum value since I want to allow my users to decide that value.

```
 <Slider
            onValueChange={changeSliderTitle}
            step={this.state.value}
            minimumValue={1}
            maximumValue={this.state.value}
          />
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `maximumValue` after it has been initialized.

There are a few issues with your current code:

```
<Slider
  onValueChange={changeSliderTitle}
  step={this.state.value}
  minimumValue={1}
  maximumValue={this.state.value}
/>
```

1. You probably want `step` to be a fixed value. It determines on what increments you can move the slider by.
2. `maximumValue` can be a value from the sate, but it should be separate from the slider value.

A fixed version of the slider could look like this.

```
<Slider
  onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({value})}}
  value={this.state.value}
  step={1}
  minimumValue={1}
  maximumValue={this.state.maxValue}
/>
```

Now, you can call the following in your code to set the maximum value of the slider dynamically.

```
this.setState({maxValue: 1000})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works nicely!
Is there a way to reset ui of the slider? The value and the maximumValue does change but but the ui does not.

Comment: Hm... could you create a snak example of the behaviour? That might make it easier to understand and debug.

Comment: there's no need for an example. It's just as described. The value changes but the UI doesn't. It's a bug.